# Sorting multidimensional vectors

Tags: sorting, vector, machine-learning

If I have a set of k vectors of n dimensions, how can I sort these such that the distance between each consecutive pair of vectors is the minimal possible? The distance can be calculated by using the Euclidian distance, but how is the "sorting" then implemented in an effective manner?

I'm thinking one approach would be to select a vector at random, calculate the distance to all other vectors, pick the vector that minimizes the distance as the next vector and repeat until all vectors have been "sorted". However, this greedy search would probably render different results depending on which vector I start with.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want just 'that the distance between each consecutive pair of vectors is the minimal possible' without randomness, you can firstly find 2 closest points (by O(n log n) algo like [this](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf)) - let's say, p and q, then search for closest points for p (let's say, r) and q (let's say, s), then compare distance (p,r) and (q,s) and if the first is smaller, start with q,p,r and use your greedy algo (in other case, obviously, start with p,q,s).

However, if your goal is actually to arrange points so that the sum of all paired distances is smallest, you should choose any approximate solution for [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution). Note [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158721/4588780) in order to reduce your task to TSP.