# Travelling salesman without returning to the starting point

Tags: shortest-path, greedy, traveling-salesman, hamiltonian-path

My question is - if we consider the Travelling salesman problem without the returning to the starting point part does the greedy (nearest neighbor) algorithm solves this problem correctly ?
In a previous thread someone stated that this problem is equivalent to the shortest Hamiltonian path, but I think we dont need the restriction on visiting every node exactly **once**, so I would like a better explenation.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried to prove or disprove it?  There is a trivial counter-example.  Also this belongs on cs.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow is for coding questions

Comment: I started to think about it because - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733999/what-is-the-problem-name-for-traveling-salesman-problemtsp-without-considering?rq=1
where no clear conclusion was made