# Given a set of points in 2d coordinates system, how to calculate the minimum distance and the path if we visit all the points only once?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The limit conditions are as below:

1. A fix threshold is set which makes distance larger than threshold are calculated by the distance itself 
   and distance less than or equal to distance are regarded as a constant value;
2. It is better to let the path increases with the x coordinates (that is p1.x <= p2.x <= ... <= pn.x), 
   but condition.1 is considered first, then the condition.2;
3. We can only visit each point for only once.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Answer (score 0):

*Note for optimization: So, basically a shortest Hamiltonian path with 2 twists (condition 1 & 2). Considering shortest HP can be solved with a Travelling Salesman algorithm (with a dummy city with zero distance from all others), for a better optimised solution you could try manipulating your distance matrix according to condition 1 before feeding it to a TSP algorithm.
More on how to use TSP for this shortest HP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733999/what-is-the-problem-name-for-traveling-salesman-problemtsp-without-considering/7158721#7158721).*

## Brute force approach

I'm gonna call your points [A, B, ...C] for readability. Let's represent our points like this:

```
+---+---+---+
|   | X | Y |
+---+---+---+
| A | 0 | 0 |
| B | 4 | 3 |
| C | 0 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

Then create a distance matrix with the Pythagorean theorem:

```
+---+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+---+------+------+------+
| A | 0.00 | 5.00 | 3.00 |
| B | 5.00 | 0.00 | 4.00 |
| C | 3.00 | 4.00 | 0.00 |
+---+------+------+------+
```

My understanding of your first condition (fix threshold) is that any distance lower than a certain value is considered zero. Apply that condition to the distance matrix (let's say it's 3.50 in our case).

```
+---+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+---+------+------+------+
| A | 0.00 | 5.00 | 0.00 |
| B | 5.00 | 0.00 | 4.00 |
| C | 0.00 | 4.00 | 0.00 |
+---+------+------+------+
```

Now, if we keep to our brute force approach, we must fund all possible permutations of routes. In our case, it's going to be simply

```
+------+-----------+--------------+
| Path | Distances | Total Length |
+------+-----------+--------------+
| ABC  | 5+4       |            9 |
| ACB  | 0+4       |            4 |
| BAC  | 5+0       |            5 |
| BCA  | 4+0       |            4 |
| CAB  | 0+5       |            5 |
| CBA  | 4+5       |            9 |
+------+-----------+--------------+
```

Remove routes that are the same but reverse.

```
+------+-----------+--------------+
| Path | Distances | Total Length |
+------+-----------+--------------+
| ABC  | 5+4       |            9 |
| ACB  | 0+4       |            4 |
| BAC  | 5+0       |            5 |
+------+-----------+--------------+
```

Take the shortest by total length and that is your solution.

## 2nd condition - distance covered on X is preferable to distance covered on Y

As far as I understood, this condition only activates if there is a tie in Total Length. In that case, create a distance matrix by using the absolute value of the difference in the points' X coordinates:

```
+---+------+------+------+
|   |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+---+------+------+------+
| A | 0.00 | 4.00 | 0.00 |
| B | 4.00 | 0.00 | 4.00 |
| C | 0.00 | 4.00 | 0.00 |
+---+------+------+------+
```

Sum up the distances according to your tied routes and use the min of that to decide which one should be preferred.