# Boost Graph: Shortest path that pass through a set of points

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I have a graph where each node is an 3D point and the edges represents the distances between those points in 3D space. The graph is not fully connected. This means between point A and B, there may be a single direct way to go or multi stage way (e.g. `A->C->D->E->B`).

I want to find the shortest closed path that passes through a given set of Points (all of points should lay on the path).

Is there a ready implementation for that in Boost Graph library?

P.S. The path should start and end from the same vertex (Cycle)

Comment: Can the waypoints be visited more than once if that is necessary?

Comment: @Albjenow Optimal case, No. But due to the noise in my waypoints, this could be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Traveling Salesmen Problem, which is NP-hard.

There's one approximation algorithm of optimal solutions in BGL: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph/doc/metric_tsp_approx.html

It assumes that the the distances have some [metric properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Metric):

> A very natural restriction of the TSP is to require that the distances between cities form a metric to satisfy the triangle inequality; that is the direct connection from A to B is never farther than the route via intermediate C:
>
> [image]

This suits your problem because your graph models points in 3D space

Comment: You should add that since he is not interested in cycles but onlys in a path, he would have to add a dummy node as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733999/what-is-the-problem-name-for-traveling-salesman-problemtsp-without-considering/7158721#7158721). This would of course invalidate the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Albjenow Actually, I needed a cycle but did not express myself correctly.. Thanks guys!